# XQuartz xterm and iTerm and oh-my-zsh themes not playing nice with each other

Tags: terminal, iterm, zsh, x11, xquartz

I typically use iTERM2 with zsh and Oh My Zsh! themes.  My current theme uses color control commands and a Powerline font:

```
# vim:ft=zsh ts=2 sw=2 sts=2

# Must use Powerline font, for \uE0A0 to render.
ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_PREFIX=" on %{$fg[magenta]%}\uE0A0 "
ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_SUFFIX="%{$reset_color%}"
ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_DIRTY="%{$fg[red]%}!"
ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_UNTRACKED="%{$fg[green]%}?"
ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_CLEAN=""

ZSH_THEME_RUBY_PROMPT_PREFIX="%{$fg_bold[red]%}‹"
ZSH_THEME_RUBY_PROMPT_SUFFIX="›%{$reset_color%}"

PROMPT='
%{$fg_bold[grey]%}%n@%m%{$fg_bold[white]%}:%{$fg_bold[green]%}$(shrink_path --fish)%{$reset_color%}$(git_prompt_info) ⌚ %{$fg_bold[red]%}%*%{$reset_color%}
$ '

RPROMPT='$(ruby_prompt_info)'
```

Anyways. On the rare occasion I need to run XQuartz with xterm.  Because of the above configuration, xterm cannot deal with the above color codes, and thus emits a bunch of garbage after each prompt:

[image: garbage after prompt in xterm]

I've tried testing for xterm using the `$TERM` variable in my .zshrc and theme files, however it's always `xterm`.

So my question, what's the best way to detect the terminal environment between XQuartz xterm and iTerm terminal so I can toggle/disable the theme?

Comment: You don't show the important parts of your script, but there is no reason that `xterm` would not support escape codes for color.  Whatever problem you have, that is not it.

Comment: What part of the script would you need?  This is the part that seemingly sets up the prompt.  If I comment out assignment of the PROMPT, everything else just works fine

Comment: @MarcWilson  With the assistance of @mmmmmm's answer, I could easily figure out the problem is that the xterm doesn't seem to want to support the `watch` emoji or SVG powerline fonts that are in use with my prompt.

Comment: Did you install the font in whatever X11 you are running?

Comment: @MarcWilson I'm using XQuartz.  Not sure where it pulls fonts from for it's xfontserver; I would assume since XQuartz is designed for MacOS, it would pull fonts from the user and system fonts directories.

Comment: There's no reason at all to assume that, X11 mostly couldn't care less about that.   Even if it did, you'd have to configure your font in `xterm` to be something that contained the Powerline set either via command-line options or Xresources.  This may be useful https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/269464/unable-to-use-correctly-powerline-with-xterm

Comment: Upon further inspection @MarcWilson XQuartz does indeed place MacOS's fonts folder on the X11 font path by default.  Oddly there seems to be either be either a bug in xterm (uxterm too) which does not correctly render Powerline fonts.  `xfd` can display the font, however they do not display correctly in the terminal.

Comment: Ok, then I'd touch base with the xterm maintainer about it not displaying the font correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try $TERM_PROGRAM this is set by iTerm.app and Terminal.app

I forget if set in xterm - but if it is unset that would be sufficient in this case.

As it is unset the the code to use is put it in this block

```
if [[ ! -z "$TERM_PROGRAM" ]]; then 
...
fi
```

Comment: This seems to work. Placing the PROMPT assignment in a `if [[ ! -z "$TERM_PROGRAM" ]]; then ...` block seems to address my immediate need.